# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations, java-17

I'm trying to enable support for @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy by defining a bean element in a config.xml file. But I'm getting error in console log stating `WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0'` Should I need any dependency for this? And I'm working on java-17. Due to this am I facing any issue? Thanks in advance.

Below I have shared the error log and dependent files for view.

***ConsoleLog***

```
Feb 27, 2023 10:36:59 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [com/sarath/spring/springcore/lc/annotations/lifeCycleBeanConfig.xml]: jakarta/annotation/Resource
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [com/sarath/spring/springcore/lc/annotations/lifeCycleBeanConfig.xml]: jakarta/annotation/Resource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:763)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:568)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.sarath.spring.springcore.lc.annotations.LifeCycleTest.main(LifeCycleTest.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/annotation/Resource
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.<clinit>(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:142)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.annotation.Resource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 22 more
```

***lifeCycleBeanConfig.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    
    <bean name="lcXML" class="com.sarath.spring.springcore.lc.annotations.PatientPojoBean" p:id="20"/>
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    
</beans>
```

***PatientPojoBean.java***

```
package com.sarath.spring.springcore.lc.annotations;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

public class PatientPojoBean {
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        System.out.println("Getting into setter");
        this.id = id;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void hi() {
        System.out.println("Hello Hi");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void bye() {
        System.out.println("Okay Bye");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PatientPojoBean [id=" + id + "]";
    }

}
```

***LifeCycleTest.java***

```
package com.sarath.spring.springcore.lc.annotations;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class LifeCycleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        AbstractApplicationContext ctxt = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/sarath/spring/springcore/lc/annotations/lifeCycleBeanConfig.xml");
        PatientPojoBean ptnt = (PatientPojoBean) ctxt.getBean("lcXML");
        System.out.println("Patient Name   : " + ptnt);
        ctxt.registerShutdownHook();    //To invoke the destroy method before closing
    }

}
```

***pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.sarath.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>springcore</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>springcore</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
     <springframework.version>6.0.5</springframework.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.29.2-GA</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because it cannot find the Jakarta annotation as Spring framework 6 requires [Jakarta EE 9+](https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6) as baseline.You have to at least upgrade the following legacy JavaEE dependencies to Jakarta EE 9+ :

Upgrade

```xml
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

And

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And if your application codes are using stuff from JavaEE , you also need to change it to use the related stuff from `jakarta` namespace.

Comment: ok. already upvoted

Answer (score 1):

For me with java 17 i use this :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```